# A kickstand has killed my touring bike. Am I wrong?

Tags: touring-bikes, kickstand

While I was cycletouring in the Nederlands last year I had someone in a bike shop install a new kickstand, longer, stronger and more effective than the previous one. He didn't put anything at all between frame and kickstand and must have tightened it very hard! The previous kickstand, also one legged, had been installed by myself, with some rubber between chainstay and kickstand and - I am sure of this - no ill effects. The bike is a good (Dawes Supergalaxy, possibly Reynolds 631), but old (year 2000) touring machine with thousands of loaded miles.
I am now doing my winter maintenance and have removed the kickstand to find the chainstay crushed, see pictures. Underneath, the crush is obvious (looks worse in the picture) and there is even a tiny hole. The above section is literally paint damage.

Am I right to think this the end of this bike? I happen to be building another touring bike at the moment but I was still planning to use this old friend for local trips and commuting. I guess now even this is not a good idea?
Any advice welcome.

[image]

Comment: What is the frame made of?  Steel?  Aluminum?  What sort of kickstand was this, a one-legged one or a two-legged one?

Comment: It seems to be a steel frame. A good metal worker should be able to repair and/or reinforce the area. Thar may not be cost-effective (depending on the cost of labor) but may be worth it if the bike has some special meaning for you.

Comment: Seems implausible that the stand caused the concave depressions running in line with the stays - those were part if the original frame, right? So the actual damage is the smaller hard edged deformations?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus I'm not sure what you mean. The claim in the question seems to be that the crush damage was caused by the kickstand: to me, that seems to be referring to the the entire area in which each chainstay doesn't have a round cross-section.

Comment: Many older steel frames i have seen have a flat spot there specifically for the kickstand. Were positive this wasn't the case and has just been marred up more because of the lack of rubber between the new kickstand and frame?

Comment: @David Richerby  [kinda like this](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/in0eWKepZ2c/maxresdefault.jpg), but positioned on the underside of the stays not the sides.

Comment: If this was crush damage, I'd expect to see matching damage on the top of the chainstays (there must have been some sort of plate to form the other side of the clamp)

Comment: The frame is steel. It was a one-legged kickstand. The crush damage appears caused by the force applying tightening the kickstand, above and below. The shape on ´the side´ is normal, similar to David Richerby´s picture. The picture from below makes it look worse than it is - you might get the idea if you see the thickness of the paint. But the chainstay is definitely crushed and does not look good. The bike feels totally normal - not sure at all I should be riding it

Comment: Yes, there was a plate, hence the crush line. The damage on the above section is insignificant by comparison, just the paint.

Comment: I suspect that the bottom of the stays was flattened in manufacture, to let the kickstand sit better.  It would be very difficult to apply torque to a kickstand mount sufficient to crush normal steel tubing.  The area needs to be checked carefully for cracks, and re-checked occasionally.  But, absent cracks, the bike should be perfectly safe to ride.

Comment: @DanielRHicks why not? Kickstand mounts have quite substantial bolts. If a diary m flat plate was used in the bottom over tightening the bolts would crush the tubes like a vise. It might even lend itself to over tightening as it doesn't hold will on the round chain stays. I don't think that a rubber liner would have helped to save the stays.

Comment: Did you contact the mechanic who did this? If this is indeed what it seems – the consequence of incompetent repair – you might claim damages. Their insurance might require a survey of the damage and an estimate of the value of the bike. Perhaps you may ask a reliable and reputable shop for advise?

Comment: This happened in the Nederlands last year and I would not be able to find the shop again - I can just remember it was outside Den Haag, on my way back to Hook van Holland - so that would be out of the question, I am afraid, although thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: You  might want to look at this link: https://surlybikes.com/info_hole/spew/kickstands_on_long_haul_truckers

Answer (score 7):

The specific points of damage I'd really be worried about are the hard edged dents near the junction with the bottom bracket shell lugs (red rectangle in pic below). I think there is a high probability that cracks will form from those points.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I reckon the flats were there but stress was concentrated by a larger-than-designed-for kickstand plate.  That would be consistent with the cosmetic damage on the top.

Comment: Thanks for all comments and answers! But I can confirm those ´flat´areas were not there originally. I agree about cracks very possibly developing in the area highlighted. Taking into account all comments and my own opinion, I will keep riding the bike locally but obviously not for extended tours and I will keep an eye on it. I will probably get a frame builder to look at it at some point soon.

Comment: The frame looks almost identical on the other chainstay. I don't use kickstands but I'm surprised that you have the same damage across both sides of the bike. Is that just how the chainstays are on that bike and the clamping isn't the whole story?

Comment: @atlaz many kickstands use a pair of plates, one above and one below the chainstays. This would cause a symmetric pattern of damage. The force from the clamp would be much greater than the force from the weight on the kickstand, even if you somehow managed to sit on the bike with it on the stand

Comment: Many frames have a flat part on the frame at that location specifically for a kickstand mount point. Maybe counter-intuitively if you did not the frame would be more prone to bending from the bottom plate of the kickstand because of the limited contact area. If you have absolutely no deformity on the top of the chainstay tubes I don't think that there is any cause for concern, though I'd probably spray paint the raw metal to prevent any surface decay that could eventually lead to failure.

Answer (score 1):

It certainly looks like cracks in the steel , which is bad. When you say a "good" bicycle, I think $ ; heat treated Cr : Mo steel that has been brazed into lugs.This construction is difficult to repair ; A bicyclist specialist shop may be able to do it but it world be expensive. If the bicycle is not so good , welded plain steel , then almost any welding shop can fix it.

Comment: There really are no cracks in the steel but there is a very tiny hole, very easy to miss. I have already rubbed off the rust and painted area. I think the frame is Reynolds 631 (these day the bike looks a bit ´tatty´and it is covered with various stickers, in part in an attempt to cover make and other things that attract unwanted attention).